# MVC controller blocking issues when published in IIS hosting server

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

We have a web application developed in MVC 4 using Razor (.Net framework 4) and we have another web application developed using .net framework 2.0 without MVC.

We are sharing form authentication using machine key and we are sharing sessions between both application by changing the application name in global.asax.

When we run our project in local environment and in local IIS aswell both of them is working normally and all the multiple requests are processed and completed as usual.

But when we publish our project in IIS hosting server form authentication, session sharing  and everything is working normally for a while but after sending multiple requests the MVC doesnot seem to process the request and its blocked so we are not able to send new requests.

Can any one please help us resolve this issue and explain where actually the problem is arising?

Thank you

Comment: Which IIS version on server and local? Do both application are in same app pool in both environment?

Comment: We are using IIS 7.5. MVC application is in ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated pool and another application is in Classic .NET AppPool (Classic framework 2.0)

Comment: Is it working with same config/app pools on local?

Comment: yes it is working with same config/app pools in local

Comment: Then please check if amount of data your request processing is same/different. It might be case your server uses different database having more data & locking on local was not noticed due to less request time.